# Uploaded file show error message, how to solve?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a place holder with image that able to upload file
then i create a condition that the file size recommended to be 100 kb or more and less than 1mb size upload

```js
var uploadField = document.getElementById("myImg");

uploadField.onchange = function() {
  // 1000000 = 1MB 
  if (this.files[0].size > 1000000) {
    alert("File is too big!");
    this.value = "";
  } else if (this.files[0].size < 100000) {
    alert("File not recommended size!");
    this.value = "";
  }
};

$('#myImg').change(function(event) {
  // var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  $("img#output").fadeIn("fast").attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));

  // $("#disp_tmp_path").html("Temporary Path(Copy it and try pasting it in browser address bar) --> <strong>["+tmppath+"]</strong>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/placeholder-avatar.jpg" id="output" width="100" height="100" style="border-radius: 50%;" />

<input id="myImg" type="file">
```

I will meet some error as what show in the code snippet like if size too big or not recommended size some error pop out

I get error like "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL'  or   "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.",

why is this happening ?

how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: You've told us what you're doing, but not what the problem is...?

Comment: hi added the error message

Comment: when the user selects a file, the UploadField.OnChange has been called and there you clear the input value, after this function the change listener has been called, and there the event.target.file is undefined so you get an error here. combine two function together

Comment: try to wrap `$("img#output")` with `if(event.target.files.length !== 0){}`

Comment: any example on how to wrap it up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    var uploadField = document.getElementById("myImg");

    uploadField.onchange = function() {
      // 1000000 = 1MB 
      if (this.files[0].size > 1000000) {
        alert("File is too big!");
        this.value = "";
      } else if (this.files[0].size < 100000) {
        alert("File not recommended size!");
        this.value = "";
      }
    };

    $('#myImg').change(function(event) {
if(event.target.files[0]){
      // var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      $("img#output").fadeIn("fast").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
}else{
  alert('Image size mismatched.')
}

      // $("#disp_tmp_path").html("Temporary Path(Copy it and try pasting it in browser address bar) --> <strong>["+tmppath+"]</strong>");
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/placeholder-avatar.jpg" id="output" width="100" height="100" style="border-radius: 50%;" />

    <input id="myImg" type="file">
```

The only thing you need to understand that Jquery will trigger as per changes so make sure to create URL Object once images are available and not unnecessary. Just enlcose your code to if else and it will work. Check the example that has been modified as per.

Comment: Thanks i got this code to call but didnt realize i am using a double same method and trying with if else to make it work....